# Counting words formed by adjacent transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra, combinatorics-on-words

I would like to find an expression for the number of words that can be formed from a given word by a certain number of adjacent transpositions (without reversing any transpositions). In particular I care about the case with only two distinct elements.

Given a word ...AABB... with n A's and m B's I would like to know how many words can be made from k adjacent transpositions. For example, consider the word AABBB, then there is one word from a single adjacent transposition, namely ABABB, two from two, BAABB and ABBAB, etc.

I would like to know this because the elements I am dealing with pick up a complex phase when commuted. I have a sum over all anagrams of these elements and need to keep track of the phases and their multiplicities so that this sum can be written as a complex number times the ordered word ...AABB...

Please let me know if my question is unclear or whether the language of words/anagrams etc. is not standard.

Comment: By transposition you mean that we can only exchange $AB$ to $BA$? Otherwise you get every possible word. You want all possible anagrams?

Comment: @Phicar that is indeed what a transposition usually means

Comment: Somewhat related: the notions of the [weak order of permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Weak_order_of_permutations) and more generally, [Bruhat order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order).

Comment: Ok, so is a riffle shuffle of A's and B's. That's what $$\binom{a+b}{a}_q$$ is.

Comment: @Phicar no I don't think it's a riffle shuffle. I only want to commute one element at a time in one direction. I only want to move A's to the right and only if there is a B next to it. Given so many moves like this I want to know how many words (anagrams of the original) it's possible to make.

Comment: yes, then is exactly it. Do you agree that summing over all possible number of movements you get $\binom{a+b}{a}$? If yes, then remember that this $q-$analogue goes over the area of some tableaux which is the same as your number of movements. If you want i can extend myself in an answer

Comment: @Phicar I don't know much about tableaux and would be very grateful if you could elaborate a little bit. Quickly looking it up, this definitely seems relevant and my own geometric attempts have involved drawing very similar diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $[n]_q=1+q+\cdots +q^{n-1}$ are the $q-$numbers. From there, one can define the $q-$factorial as $[n]_q!=[n]_q[n-1]_q\cdots [2]_q[1]_q.$ As an intermediate exercise one can see that $$[n]_q=\sum _{i = 0}^{\binom{n}{2}}A_{n,i}q^i,$$
where $A_{n,i}=|\{\sigma \in S_n:|Inv(\sigma)|=i\}|,$ so number of permutations with $i$ inversions.
 As you have factorials, then you can define binomials, so you define $$\binom{a+b}{b}_q=\frac{[a+b]_q!}{[a]_q![b]_q!}=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty}B_{a,b,i}q^i,$$ you can show that with the description of the coefficients $A_{n,i}$ you will get that $B_{a,b,i}$ can be represented as the number of Young diagrams (i.e., tuples $(r_1,\cdots, r_k)$ such that $\sum _j r_j = i$ and $k\leq b$ and $r_1 \leq a$ and $r_1\geq r_2\geq \cdots \geq r_k>0$) inside the rectangle $[0,a]\times [0,b]$ in the plane with area $i.$
 Now, the claim is that if we call $a$ the number of $A's$ in your string and $b$ number of $B's$ and $i$ the number of transpositions, then $B_{a,b,i}$ is your answer. Let's enumerate the A's and B's on your string for a moment, so $x=A_1\cdots A_aB_1\cdots B_b$ so note that if you move $A_a$ say $r_1$ times, then you can move $A_{a-1}$(called the number of transpositions $r_2$) the same amount or less (so you get $r_1\geq r_2 \geq \cdots \geq r_a\geq 0$). Notice also that you can not move $A_a$ more times that the numbers of B's, so $b\geq r_1$ and note then that the total amount of movements is $r_1+r_2+\cdots +r_a$ So, do you see know that this is exactly the same?

Comment: This is exactly what I need thank you! In particular if I have the sum over all anagrams of a word with a A's and b B's, and also have that BA = q AB then this sum is equal to $$ \binom{a+b}{b}_q A\cdots AB\cdots B.$$

I've never seen q-analogues before and they seems very interesting and useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help and you are right about the observation.